# How do I get an Intel Ultimate 6300-N working?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, intel-wireless

First off I upgraded my Wifi card from a ralink to a Intel Ultimate-N 6300 and also had to install a Modded bios so the computer would accept the wifi card. I can get my wifi to connect in Windows but when I try to install any linux tried Ubuntu's, Crunchbang, Archbang etc. the wifi card is recognized but when i try to connect to any router I get an endless loop of it trying to connect. if the router had a wep key it will go in an endless loop for about 45 seconds then re ask for the password if the router doesnt have a password it will just sit in an endless loop saying connecting. The computer is a dv6-6135dx with a AMD chipset has the 3500m processor in it 6620g integraded graphics with a 6750m graphic card also. Could it be a conflict between the AMD chipset and the wifi card needing a intel chipset driver? Here is some more detail.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:422b] (rev 3e)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN [8086:1101]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 53
    Memory at f0200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlagn
    Kernel modules: iwlagn
```

also have done:

```
sudo rmmod iwwlagn
sudo modprobe iwlagn bt_coex_active=0
```

this allows me to connect to the wifi but only on that session of Ubuntu if i restart i have to go back into terminal and retype also i am noticing slow speeds after doing that. Any suggestions?

What I've tried:

- According to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/654152) these cards might have a hard time when in 802.11n mode. Doing a `sudo modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=0` just makes it get stuck in an endless loop trying to connect.

Answer (score 1):

## If you have modprobe parameters you already know work:

If that modprobe parameter works for you, as root add a file in modprobe.d that makes the setting persist, like this:

1. As `root` with your text editor of choice make a new file:

   ```
    /etc/modprobe.d/customintel6300N.conf
   ```
2. In that file add the line:

   ```
    options iwlagn bt_coex_active=0
   ```
3. Save and reboot.

Wireless N can be finicky on a lot of cards, but if you found modprobe settings that work for you...just make them persist.  It doesn't solve the slow problem, but it does get you running consistently.

## If you don't:

#### Disabling hardwarecrypto:

Some users have reported that N support gets much more reliable using software you might try

```
options iwlagn hwcrypto=0
```

instead of the `coex` option.

#### Disabling n:

As was already suggested by [Jorge Castro](https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro):

```
options iwlagn 11n_disable=0
```

Comment: is there any other way we can fix this? my laptop disconnects from the internet every like 2 minutes then reconnects after 2 more minutes