# How can I troubleshoot problems with an Intel wireless card?

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

How can I troubleshoot the issue?

Problems range through:

1. Poor connection speeds
2. Dropped connections
3. Failure to connect
4. Seemingly random disconnects
5. Poor range
6. Card is stuck in `hardware disabled` state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in all cases `iwlagn` should be replaced with your wireless module name.  In my case `iwlwifi`.

**Options for connection speed**

The coex option:

*Notes:*
It would be good form to change the `customintel6300N.conf` part to the name of your driver or card so you can easily find out where you tweaked the module parameters.  `lsmod | grep iwl` should tell you what driver/module you're using.  In my case it's `iwlwifi`

As root add a file in modprobe.d that makes the setting persist, like this:

1. As `root` with your text editor of choice make a new file:

   ```
   /etc/modprobe.d/customintel6300N.conf
   ```
2. In that file add a line like:

   ```
   options iwlagn bt_coex_active=0
   ```
3. Save and reboot.

**Disabling hardwarecrypto**

Some users have reported that N support gets much more reliable using software you might try

```
options iwlagn hwcrypto=0
```

instead of the `coex` option.

**Disabling N support**
As was already suggested by [Jorge Castro](https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro):

```
options iwlagn 11n_disable=0
```

**Recovering from stuck in hardware disabled state**

1. Remove all power sources(cables/batteries).
2. Act like you're powering on the device(press and hold the power button or power cycle several times even though it has no power).
3. Reconnect all power sources and boot.

The goal of that set is to remove power from wherever the wireless card stores the hardware disabled state and defaults to 'enabled' on the next boot.

Related questions:
[How do I get an Intel 6300 N working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109260/how-do-i-get-an-intel-ultimate-6300-n-working)