# Pluscom MAC address shows up but "wireless unavailable"

Tags: wireless, networking, 12.10, network-manager

I've got a pluscom pci card plugged into my desktop and although the mac address shows up in network manager, it says "Wireless unavailable".

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 Gnome Shell Remix...

```
edgar@edgarQuantal:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

edgar@edgarQuantal:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:f0:49:02:1f:b8  
          inet addr:192.168.0.7  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6ef0:49ff:fe02:1fb8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1425 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1393 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:995753 (995.7 KB)  TX bytes:134079 (134.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:40828 (40.8 KB)  TX bytes:40828 (40.8 KB)
```

It looks the same as the problem as here, seems quite complicated: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1993226

Tried downloading the driver but I get this:

```
Unpacking firmware-ralink (from .../firmware-ralink_0.36_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /home/edgar/Downloads/firmware-ralink_0.36_all.deb (--install):
trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/rt2870.bin', which is also in package linux-firmware 1.95"
```

Comment: Are you running 32- or 64-bit Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

An interface should always have a MAC address associated with it.  If it says "wireless unavailable" I would expect that you are not seeing or associating with an access point or wireless switch/router.

Does your wireless work from a different OS, a different device, or from your system running from a LiveCD/DVD?

For general troubleshooting, see this [help.ubuntu.com page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers).

See [Broadcom 4312 wireless issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102282/broadcom-4312-wireless-issues) and https://askubuntu.com/questions/57554/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-installation-of-the-latest-broadcom-driver

Also try resetting power (via [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/181870) ) :

> Remove all power sources(cables/batteries).
>     Act like you're powering on the device (press and hold the power button or power cycle several times even though it has no power).
>       Reconnect all power sources and boot.
>
> The goal of that set is to remove power from wherever the wireless
>   card stores the hardware disabled state and defaults to 'enabled' on
>   the next boot.

Based on the forum thread you mention, you might try this driver: http://packages.debian.org/sid/all/firmware-ralink/download .

Comment: I presumed that because network manager sees that the card exists that it should work. Instead it says its disabled and therefore I can't even scan to see SSIDs never mind connecting. The card is enabled both physically and through the software as shown in the terminal. I have tried installing the broadcom drivers from the software centre but these make no difference.

Comment: Can you see SSIDs with any other devices?   Can you add the ifconfig output (obfuscating as necessary) as an edit to your original?

Comment: On the gnome shell remix live cd it says the device is not ready, can see the ssid on my laptop which I'm using right now.